# Convert string to lowercase in PROLOG

Tags: prolog

I have some homework for PROLOG, and I'm trying to convert a string to lowercase without using the built in `string_lower/2` function on Prolog.

The code I'm using right now (I got it from another post in stack overflow):

```
lowercase(AnyCaseList, DownCaseList):-
    maplist(downcase_atom, AnyCaseList, DownCaseList).
```

I'm trying to adapt it so I can use it like that:

```
lowercase(‘COmpuTAblE’, X).
X = computable'
```

But no matter what I use as input, it always just gives the answer "no" and nothing else.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: so easy: `lowercase([‘COmpuTAblE’], [X]).`. Can you see why ?

Comment: `downcase_atom('COmpuTAblE', X).` It operates on the whole atom, not a character at a time. You don't need `maplist`.